# How to add additional non-entity fields to entity form in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I have created form with one element from Entity:

```
$promo = new Promo();

$form = $this->createFormBuilder($promo)
        ->add('code', 'text')
        ->getForm();
```

And I want to add file element (this field doesn't exist in the Entity). When I do:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($promo)
        ->add('code', 'text')
        ->add('image', 'file')
        ->getForm();
```

I have an error: Neither property "image" nor method "getImage()". How can I add this field?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Use [mapped](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#mapped):

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($promo)
    ->add('code', 'text')
    ->add('image', 'file', array(
                "mapped" => false,
            ))
    ->getForm();
```

In old Symfony versions (2.0 and earlier), use [property_path](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#property-path):

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($promo)
    ->add('code', 'text')
    ->add('image', 'file', array(
                "property_path" => false,
            ))
    ->getForm();
```

"property_path" was removed in Symfony 2.3

Comment: Cool. Didn't know about the `mapped` option.

Comment: Thanks. I will use property_path = false.

Comment: It was helpful also on SF4

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`property_path`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#property-path) option:

```php
$builder->add('image', 'file', [
    'property_path' => false,
]);
```

Comment: This is removed since Symfony 2.3. The new way is to use `mapped` like in the new correct answer.