# add a text area to form symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I have a form related to an entity. I want to add a text area number to the form and get the value entred, knowing that I don't have an attribute in the entity with this value so neither `getNumber()` nor setNumber. I also want it to be submitted with the form.

How can I achieve that?

I found out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12384414/how-to-add-additional-non-entity-fields-to-entity-form-in-symfony2) and tried

```
->add('From', 'text', array(
                "property_path" => false,
            ));
```

But what I want to know how to get this value now? can it be submitted with the form?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12384414/how-to-add-additional-non-entity-fields-to-entity-form-in-symfony2?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

The value will be submitted with the form. Therefore you can retrieve it directly in the "Request" object.

In your case you would do

```
$this->get('request')->request->get('From');
```

See the [cookbook about form without classes](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#using-a-form-without-a-class) for more information.

---

You can also retrieve the request object by having a parameter of the type [Request](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html) in your function :

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

public function myFunction(Request $request /*, ... */){
    //...

    $from = $request->get('From');

    //...
}
```